# Trying to display Grafana web pages in android webview mobile application

Tags: android, xamarin, webview, grafana

I am trying to develop a mobile application that will display Grafane web pages in the application. I use androif WebView. It displays other web pages but when it comes to Grafana it gives below warning.

If you're seeing this Grafana has failed to load its application files

1. This could be caused by your reverse proxy settings.
2. If you host grafana under subpath make sure your grafana.ini root_url setting includes subpath. If not using a reverse proxy make sure to set serve_from_sub_path to true.
3. If you have a local dev build make sure you build frontend using: yarn start, yarn start:hot, or yarn build
4. Sometimes restarting grafana-server can help

There is no proxy configured. Grafana serves web with its default webserver.

I can embed grafana web pages to another sites. But it gives error trying to embed grafana web pages in android webviev.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same issue.
It wasn't working until I added settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true)

```
    mywebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings settings = mywebView.getSettings();
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```